# Linux shell script read columns into variable and then add the attribute

Tags: linux, parsing, shell, variables

I have a file test.txt looking like this:

```
2092 Mary
103 Tom
1239 Mary
204 Mark
1294 Tom
1092 Mary
```

I am trying to create a shell script that will

1. Read each line and put the data in two columns into variable var1 and var2
2. If var2 in each line is the same, then add the var1 in those lines.
3. output the file into a text file.

The result should be unique values in the var2 column. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/usr/bin/sh
cat test.txt| while read line;
do
$var1=$(echo $line| awk -F\; '{print $1}')
$var2=$(echo $line| awk -F\; '{print $2}')
```

How can I reference the variable in each line and then compare them? 
The expected output would be:

```
4423 Mary
1397 Tom 
204  Mark
```

Comment: What about using `sort -s -n k 1` and then `-u` to get unique values?

Comment: Can you add the expected output ? Thanks

Comment: no `done`? and `$var1=`, you probably mean `var1=...`. Finally, no need to split line in such a convoluted way. `while read num name; do ... ; done < test.txt`. Finally, finally, agree with fedorqui that `sort` can do what you need, unless this is just a sketch of your problem. Doing uniqueness in shell code without `sort` and/or `uniq` is not trival. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` it is easy:

```
awk '{sum[$2] += $1} END {for (i in sum) printf "%4d %s\n", sum[i], i; }'
```

If you want to do it with `bash` 4.x (not 3.x), then:

```
declare -A sum
while read number name
do
    ((sum[$name] += $number))
done

for name in "${!sum[@]}"
do
    echo ${sum[$name]} $name
done
```

The structure here is essentially isomorphic with the `awk` script, but a little less notationally convenient.  It will read from standard input, using the names as indexes into the associative array `sum`.  The `${!sum[@]}` notation is described in the [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) section of the manual, and not even hinted at in the section on [Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays).  The information is there if you know where to look.

If you want to process an arbitrary number of input files (like the `awk` script would) then you need to use `cat` to collect the data:

```
cat "$@" |
{
declare -A sum
while read number name
do
    ((sum[$name] += $number))
done

for name in "${!sum[@]}"
do
    echo ${sum[$name]} $name
done
}
```

This is not [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) because it handles no arguments (read standard input), one argument or many arguments.

For all the scripts, if you want to sort the output in number or name order, apply an appropriate `sort` to the output of the script:

```
script file1 file2 file3 | sort -k 1,1n     # By sum increasing order
script file1 file2 file3 | sort -k 1,1nr    # By sum decreasing order
script file1 file2 file3 | sort -k 2,2      # By name increasing order
script file1 file2 file3 | sort -k 2,2r     # By name decreasing order
```

Comment: You need `bash` 4.2 and the `lastpipe` option to let `sum` be visible after the `while` loop, though. An outer loop of `for f; do while ...; done < "$f"; done` should work, though.

Comment: Or perhaps `while read number name; do ...; done < <( cat "$@" )`, which should also work with zero arguments, unlike my previous comment.

Comment: @chepner: Oh —drat! It's always dangerous not to test 'enhancements', even simple ones.  Thanks — I'll fix it, my way, using `{ ... }` to group the operational part of the script into a single unit for redirection of the `cat` output.